# Cannot get value from Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having trouble retrieving data from the Redux store. Redux logger is showing the data but can't seem to get it to render. Below is the code for my container component and my action/reducer:

```
//COMPONENT:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchGrade } from '../../modules/smiles';

class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchSmile();
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    const { smiles } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is the Main Component</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { smiles: state.smiles };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchSmile: params => dispatch(fetchGrade(params))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

//ACTION/REDUCER:
import axios from 'axios';
const ADD_GRADE = 'SMILES/ADD_GRADE';

export function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_GRADE:
      return {
        ...state,
        grade: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const fetchGrade = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .get('/api/test')
      .then(res => dispatch({ type: ADD_GRADE, payload: res.data }));
  };
};

//STORE:
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import reducer from '../modules';

let store;

export function configureStore(state: {}) {
  if (!store) {
    store = createStore(
      reducer,
      state,
      composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(logger, thunk))
    );
  }

  return store;
}

//INDEX.JS:
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { configureStore } from './store';

window.store = configureStore();

render(
  <Provider store={window.store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

I really don't know if this is complicated or an easy fix. I feel like I'm doing everything right but no luck.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your reducer.js file of the modules directory?

Comment: Here is the code in the reducer file in the module director:
import axios from 'axios';
const ADD_GRADE = 'SMILES/ADD_GRADE';

export function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_GRADE:
      return {
        ...state,
        grade: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const fetchGrade = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .get('/api/test')
      .then(res => dispatch({ type: ADD_GRADE, payload: res.data }));
  };
};

Comment: I am asking the code for the reducer which you have imported for configureStore. `import reducer from '../modules';` - this one

Comment: sorry about that:
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { reducer as smiles } from './smiles';

export default combineReducers({
  smiles
});

Comment: Is `console.log(smiles)` in render function giving `undefined`?

Comment: yes! it shows up as undefined when I console.log(smiles) within the render function:
render() {
    const smiles = this.props.smiles;
    console.log('from render(): ', smiles);
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );

Answer (score 1):

You named your reducer, `reducer`:

```
export function reducer(state = {}, action) {
```

Seems that you forgot to access it from your `reducer` object. it should be something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { smiles: state.reducer.smiles };
};
```

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work for me. I'm getting and Object Undefined error